# How to make both select and input in the same element?

Tags: html

How to make both select and input in the same element, so that I can type in the input when there is no desired option?

```
<div class="form-group">
     <label for="editAppointmentContact" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Customer Name</label>
           <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select class="form-control select2contact" id="editAppointmentContact" ></select>
           </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Check out the [`datalist`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) element - it does what you're looking for.

Comment: I believe you're looking for a [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist)

You can read more about the details of how to use them [here](https://www.jotform.com/blog/html5-datalists-what-you-need-to-know-78024/)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're looking for [Select2](https://select2.org/) which is an input/select in one. It uses JQuery but I know there's a VueJS and ReactJS wrappers for this component.

If this does not meet your exact needs you can use [datalist](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/datalist) which is a HTML5 element and it is not [completely supported](https://caniuse.com/#search=datalist) yet.